# Issues connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, ping

I'm trying to boot up a sitecore application.  Got the source code, set up my local IIS, but for some reason I'm getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I figure that it's probably an issue hitting the correct server, so I open up the connection strings config file, copy the server name (named for our purposes: `SERVERX`).

Using command line I try to ping `SERVERX`.

The ping fails. It's trying to hit `SERVERX.COMPANYA.NET`. Server X is run by Company B.  I had done some work for company A prior.

So:  why is `.COMPANYA.NET` being appended to the server name? Is there a way to prevent that? Would `SERVERX.COMPANYA.NET` be the address that the locally run website would try to hit?

Note: I'm on company A's & B's VPNS at the same time. Would this be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've likely got CompanyA.net set as a search suffix on your network adapter. You can verify this by looking at `ipconfig /all`. If that's the case, remove it from there and replace it with the correct DNS domain for your current situation.

Comment: And/Or if you have to force it manually, just change the local `hosts` file to point the IP to SERVERX.COMPANYB.NET temporarily.

Comment: ok, so I managed to get "ping SERVERX" to resolve into SERVERX.COMPANYX.COM.  The IP that it resolves into is not the IP that the server actual is.  (I can RDP onto the server & ping it by IP, just not by name)

Comment: Most likely, COMPANYB has different public and private DNS entries for that server. In that case, you could follow TheCleaner's comment to force that DNS name to resolve to the IP you desire. Perhaps an even simpler method would be to just use the IP address directly in the connection string.